# DT Package PDF Extension Button

Tags: javascript, r, pdf, shiny, shinyjs

I have a rather large table, that if I fit it into the `DT` table and do a PDF print on it, there will be portions of the column that will be cut off. Also, I wanted to adjust the size of the title when exporting it to the PDF as well. How should I go about this?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about when all the columns don't fit into one page. **How do I adjust the size of the table and the title inside the `DT` table PDF?**

```
library("shiny")
library("DT")

data <- cbind(iris,iris,iris)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      data,extensions="Buttons",options = list(dom = 'Bt',
                                               buttons = list( list( extend = 'pdf',
             pageSize = 'A4',
             orientation = 'landscape',
             filename = 'tt',
            title= "A smaller title here")))
      )
  }
    )
```

Several things I've tried:

1. **`capture` package**: Will print the entire table to how I adjust and format the table in Shiny, but all in *one* PDF page, which is not ideal since I want the PDF to be printable over several A4 pages.
2. **Putting in a `width` argument in `DTOutput`**: Will not show up adjusted in the PDF export table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `customize` callback of the `pdf` extension to change the `pdfMake` options, which is the workhorse of the pdf rendering. For example you can set the column width such that each column uses only a percentage of the total width.

Similarly, you can change the styling of the title with the same idea:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js_cb <- JS("function(pdf_opts, btn, dt) {
                let n = pdf_opts.content[1].table.body[0].length;
                // each column occupies a percentage of the total width
                let widths = Array(n).fill(100 / n + '%');
                pdf_opts.content[1].table.widths = widths; 
                pdf_opts.styles.title.fontSize = 8; // change fontsize
             }")

data <- cbind(iris,iris,iris)

shinyApp(
   ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
   server = function(input, output) {
      output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
         data,
         extensions = "Buttons",
         options = list(dom = "Bt",
                        buttons = list(list(extend = "pdf",
                                            pageSize = "A4",
                                            orientation = "landscape",
                                            filename = "tt", 
                                            customize = js_cb,
                                            title = "A smaller title here")))
      )
   }
)
```